# Duplicating JSON Web Token from NodeJS on Python

Tags: python, node.js, jwt, python-3.6

I'm trying to call an `NodeJS` API with `jsonwebtoken` authentication from a Lambda function written in Python. The problem is I cannot get them to generate the same token

NodeJS Code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let token = jwt.sign({ "_id": "lambda-functions" }, 'my-secret', { algorithm: 'HS256'});
```

Resulting token:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiJsYW1iZGEtZnVuY3Rpb25zIiwiaWF0IjoxNTY4MjI3NjQzfQ.fjR9oe4cPlptol4f6U8hhSQCZAFl_vAfslQ1Uqkkogk

Python Code:

```
import jwt
token = jwt.encode({"_id": "lambda-functions"},  "my-secret", algorithm="HS256")
decoded_token =  token.decode('utf-8')
```

Resulting Token:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiJsYW1iZGEtZnVuY3Rpb25zIn0.3P5PnZW7-TRUt0ShAKPqs74KQqC8apa-MTLhtcoeGZQ

Comment: the difference is, that the node-js generated token contains an additional `iat`claim in the payload and the values in the headers are in different order. But anyway, as long as the tokens are technically correct and can be verified, what does it matter if they are different? Why is that a problem? For me it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: I thought they had to be the same to verify. Let me test if it works

Comment: No, it won't verify

Comment: I really don't know what you're doing.Ususally you have one token, issued on server side and verified on server side (often the same program). Verify is usally a function in the jwt packagew that takes the token to verify and a secret or key. Why and where do you need to tokens?

Comment: I'm trying to hit the NodeJS API from a Lambda function. So, it is issued on the API server and re-generated on a different server. Is this possible?